# Issue with Django Forms saving data

Tags: python, django, database, model-view-controller

I am trying to make a Django web application which saves information about a User and his Hobbies to a local database. For some reason it isn't working and I am having trouble figuring out the issue. Here is my code:

The models.py file:

```
my_choices = (
    (0, "None"),
    (1, "Football"),
    (2, "Cricket"),
    (3, "Swimming"),
    (4, "Cycling"),
)

class Hobby(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    field = models.IntegerField(choices=my_choices, default=0)
```

The views.py function for Profile:

```
def profile(request,user):

    try:
        profile_object = Profile.objects.get(id=user)

        if request.method.POST:
            form = HobbyForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                profile_object.field = form.cleaned_data["field"]
                profile_object.save()

                context = {
                        "form": form,
                        "profile": profile_object,
                    }
                return render(request, 'mainapp/profile.html', context)

            else:
                context = {
                        "form": form,
                        "profile": profile_object,
                    }
                return render(request, 'mainapp/profile.html', context)
        else:
            context = {
                        "form": form,
                        "profile": profile_object,
                    }
            return render(request, 'mainapp/profile.html', context)

    except Profile.DoesNotExist:
        context = {
            "form": form,
            "profile": profile_object,
        }
        return render(request, 'mainapp/profile.html', context)
```

The forms.py code for the actual form:

```
class HobbyForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Hobby
        fields = ["field"]
```

And the profile.html page:

```
<form action="myurl/{{profile.id}}/" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{% form.as_p %}
<input type="submit" value="OK">
</form>
```

When I run this code, I get the following error:

```
TypeError at /profile/
int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Member'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/profile/
Django Version: 2.1.3
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Member'
Exception Location: C:\Users\install\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py in get_prep_value, line 965
Python Executable:  C:\Users\install\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe
Python Version: 3.6.3
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\install\\Documents\\coursework\\Mumin',
 'C:\\Users\\install\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\python36.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\install\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\install\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\install\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36',
 'C:\\Users\\install\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python36\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\install\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Wed, 12 Dec 2018 17:09:26 +0000
```

Essentially what I am trying to do with this is to allow a logged in User to add some Hobbies they are interested in and save them to the database. The hobbies are predefined in the Models. For some reason, this code is not achieveing what I want and I am not sure why. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`<form action="myurl/{{profile.id}}/" method="post">` in this line you are trying to pass an id to view.py but actually, you are not doing this. The correct way of doing it is

```
{% url 'yoururlnameassosiatedwithdesiredview' id=id %}
```

And the error is raised here:

```
profile_object = Profile.objects.get(id=user)
```